# how to show 2 properties in typeahead angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using the angular bootstrap typeahead:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" selectState(state.id) typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)'  typeahead="state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

At the moment I am displaying the state.name property. Is there a quick way of displaying state.id and state.name together in the input?

plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PVXPUiUmLyi80XkY5F9V?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" selectState(state.id) typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)'  typeahead="(state.id + ' ' + state.name) for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

Changed `state.name` to `(state.id + ' ' + state.name)`